# Optimal exercises for an abdominal workout

Tags: exercise, weightlifting, abdominals

In response to [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/crunches-before-or-after-sit-ups/1242#1242), I was curious what exercises specifically target the abdominal muscles. Answers given so far include:

- Works abs directly:

  - [leg raises](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/HipFlexors/WtVerticalStraightLegRaise.html)
  - [rollout](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/HipFlexors/BWKneelingWheelRollout.html)
- Indirectly:

  - squats

My question is two-fold:

1. What's wrong with the age-old [crunch](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/RectusAbdominis/WtCrunch.html)?
2. What other good abdominal exercises are there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Probably the biggest problem with the age old crunch is that it is not functional.   The crunch flexes the trunk and primarily targets the rectus abdominis, not the transversus abdominis or the obliques.  If you want a flexed trunk when you stand up then doing lots of crunches will give it to you.

However, if you want an elongated mid section with strong abdominal muscles creating a solid core and support for your abdomen then you want to use postural exercises such as [the plank](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Stability-Fitness.html), progressing the length of time you are able to maintain the hold, which translates into functionally controlling the torso.  Also, by drawing your navel in towards the spine with these types of exercises you target the transversus abdominis which flattens the abdominal wall more than other ab muscles.  The transversus is especially important in lifting.

If your goal is to have 6 pack abs then you need a low percentage of body fat which is generally achieved  with diet, HIIT and strength training to burn calories.

Some suggestions of other good abdominal exercises that carry over into improved posture and function are: [The plank, side plank, bird dog](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Stability-Fitness.html#Stabilization_Exercise_Video),  progressing to dynamic control with [dying bug](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsqCDbiflsg), [knee tucks on a swiss ball](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y03dkaK1O0&feature=related)  or [swiss ball roll outs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixWEAcZf58M&feature=relatedhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsqCDbiflsg).  Using [resistance bands helps to target the obliques](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XRe6HA7DVo).

Comment: Dear @BackInShapeBuddy, fantastic info, thanks: just to clarify: do you put leg raises in the same category as crunches, or in the let's say "better" category of planks.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe, In this [leg raise](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/RectusAbdominis/WtVerticalLegHipRaise.html) link you will see that there is a stabilization as well as dynamic function of the abs (see the comment area).  Also, whether done in this position or in the [hanging leg raise position](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wr4-McBOJCg), you can see that it adds more to your workout as it is more of a total body exercise than crunches.  Go for it!

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks!  FYI my favorite ab exercise is [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-8jNoh_ojA#t=2m30s).  It's SUPER tough and has lots of scalability.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the more advanced versions of leg raises are:

[windmill](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0naOASvxJX8&feature=related)

[inclined leg raises](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lixlXHY3zi4)

[hanging leg jacknife](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wr4-McBOJCg)

And when you get strong enough, you can do weighted versions of these. You can use a dumbbell in between your feet for the weighted version, just be careful though.

Comment: basically you do those 3 when you hit plateau on the normal leg raises.

Comment: +1 for the windmill. After [flag](http://www.stayfitbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/human-flag-exercise.jpg), in my opinion, the hardest abdomenal exercise.

Comment: speaking of flag, I forgot to mention something similar to that, its called the dragonfly, from bruce lee, but this link here is from rocky 4. I don't do it too much as I'm not strong enough for that one: [link] http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihky09eKsEI&feature=related

Comment: The windmil  vid is broken, one thing with leg raises is you can do them laying flat but on a high platform and have your legs hang off the edge. The advantage of this is then you are actively contracting through 270 degrees of motion as opposed to 180 degrees with hanging leg raises. (If you were to front lever, but let your legs hang down that would accomplish the same but is much harder)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with crunches is that they aren't very effective for the purposes that most people choose them:

- If you are doing crunches because you want to show off a "six-pack" then you'll never get there, as this is mostly about getting to low body fat rather than building larger ab muscles.
- If you are trying to increase core strength, then crunches are equivalent to doing a very high-rep low-weight exercise, which does not build strength.

Comment: What's stopping you from grabbing 30 kg weight? Suddenly, crunches are low-rep high-weight exercise which does build strength.

Comment: Nothing, but that's no longer an "age-old crunch", it's a modified version...

Answer (score 0):

Someone above described planks as a "postural exercise".  That might be true in theory, but in practice it is a different matter.  Visit your typical gym and just watch the people doing their planks.  They are all doing terrible things for their posture.  Their scapulas are winging, their thoracic spine is going into kyphosis (hunchback), and their cervical spine is protracted (forward head posture).  This is especially the case when people try to do planks for a maximum amount of time, which is fashionable on facebook and youtube.

If you are going to do planks, have someone watch you and adjust you and keep you honest. Once your form shows any sign of deterioration, stop.  After that point, you will just be imprinting bad posture into your nervous system (engram).

Answer (score -1):

I don't do ab exercises yet I can see my abs. What I do targets them indirectly, squats, dead-lifts, standing shoulder press, shrugs, etc. For the little time I have to train, 2 for 1 (ie full body exercises) is the best way to go.

Comment: What is more optimal, having a strong core or having an unbalanced core just for the sake of having a "6 pack" and ignoring the other regions of the core?