# What is the best way to strengthen your abs?

Tags: exercise-technique, hernia

I have [hiatus hernia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_hernia) and lumbar hernia so the doctor forbade me to do situps. Is there a way to work my abs, having these conditions? Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at this q/a with alternative [ab exercise](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/optimal-exercises-for-an-abdominal-workout/3372#3372) and ask your doctor if any of them are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I learned from [Elliott Hulse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCbf2wqE4Gw) that actually made me stop doing silly abdominal exercises that gave minimal results.

Its called the [stomach vacuum exercise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_exercise). This exercise involves contracting your **internal** abdominal muscles by breathing out all the air in your lungs momentarily thus creating a vacuum and then breathing back in. Not the external ones. If you watch Elliott Hulse video at 5.47  you can see how the exercise is performed. Ever wonder why you see some professional bodybuilders with an amazing physique and bloated abs?

A fine example of what I mean; bloated vs flat [image]

This exercise is a forgotten simple way to promote healthier, stronger internal abdominal. As a fitness community, we have become obsessed with external results that we forget about our insides and internal muscles.

Another fine example of a great legendary bodybuilder who has strong internal abs;

[image]

This exercise will not only give you strength in your abs but it will improve your posterior chain and in turn may help with your condition.

**Patience is key with this exercise**. Don't expect immediate results after doing this and make sure you take your time doing it. **Less is more**.

I hope you get better soon.