# Slightly visible abs, but bloated belly after eating

Tags: abdominals

I've been training for abs several weeks ago, and thanks to this site and some users who answered my question, my abs started to be slightly visible. However, after I eat, my belly become bloated again, and it isn't until the next day morning can I see my abs again.

I don't have a big meal, and I'm not eating unhealthy food, like pizza, fried chicken, or hamburgers. I'm not eating very quickly, and I don't talk when I'm eating. I'm not allergic to any food.

What happened to my belly? What workouts or anything can I do to avoid this situation happening?

Comment: The only thing you can really do is to trust the process and continue doing things right. Eventually your abs will grow bigger, and as you lose fat they will be more and more visible. The bloating of your stomach will always happen, but over time as you develop better abs the bloating won't prevent you from being able to see your abs.

Comment: @EricWarburton I'm simply asking about the situation of bloated belly after eating, as I've said in my question, I can see abs the other day, so I'm not worried about it. I just want to ask about why this situation is happening.

Comment: @EricWarburton So does that explain why there are five downvotes in my question?

Comment: I'm not sure why there are downvotes on the question. Perhaps someone who downvoted can elaborate if they see this.

Comment: @EricWarburton Do you think I should raise this issue on meta? Or will that only attract more downvotes?

Comment: I don't see why you would, Thomas gave you the correct answer.

Comment: You talk about visible abs, but are you also targeting the transverse abdominals? These are important deep control muscle.  This answer may be of some help.  https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/optimal-exercises-for-an-abdominal-workout/3372#3372

Answer (score 5):

“What happened to my belly?”

It is full of food.

“What workouts can I do?”

No workout will prevent your stomach from expanding when you eat.

“How can I prevent this?”

You can’t, unless you just don’t eat. You should eat.

Comment: How about the solution? What can I do to make my belly smaller after eating? And it is normal that the situation disappears until the next morning?

Comment: @Eden0516 You can wait for your body to digest the food.

Comment: He might also have a pelvic tilt